# Right click on UIButton for UIKitForMac (catalyst)

Tags: swift, uibutton, mac-catalyst, uikitformac

Is it possible to easily enable right click on a Mac Catalyst app within UIKitForMac?

Currently the following code works perfectly on left click, but nothing is called on right click:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doSomething), for: .touchUpInside)
```

// Is called for left click but not for right click

```
@objc func doSomething(sender:UIButton, event:UIEvent) -> Bool {
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/context-menus/

This menu works by right clicking on Mac Catalyst

**1. Add Iteraction**

```
let interaction = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
 yourButton.addInteraction(interaction)
```

**2. Add extension UIContextMenuIteractionDelegate**

```
extension AccountViewVC: UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {

 public func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
      
      return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: { suggestedActions in
           let delete = UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow")) { action in
                
           }
           let children = [delete]
           return UIMenu(title: "Main Menu", children: children)
      })
 }}
```

Comment: This is almost the solution, however if you have a UIButton, the touchUpInside event is still called meaning you get a right click event AND a left click..

Comment: Strange, I just checked, the touchUpInside event is not called for me when I right-click

Comment: Yes right click on macOS works as intended, however on iOS, long press to trigger the context menu ALSO calls touchUpInside.

Comment: Use targetEnvironment to differentiate
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)